# Reuse data in a Tensorflow graph (using Queues and tf.cond())

Tags: if-statement, tensorflow, control-flow

I'm building a `resample layer` in Tensorflow that is meant to reuse data for `resample_n`-times before getting new data from the `net_data_layer()` (a Que reading from some hdf5 datasources). I have a Network class and store the tensors returned from the data layer in it (`self`) for "global" access (e.g. for building the network-graph, but also by my `train_op()`):

```
self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights = net_data_layer()
```

I added some logic so that in the first iteration `resample == False`, with the intention of data-layer queues being called, and then `resample == True` for the next `resample_n`-th iterations. The part in the graph boils down to:

```
self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights = \
    tf.cond(resample, 
            lambda: resample_data(), 
            lambda: net_data_layer())
```

Where `resample_data()` just returns the previously stored data, basically doing nothing but forwarding the already stored data to the graph:

```
def resample_data(): return self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: Operation 'ResampleLayer/cond/DataLayer_hdf5_dset/test_data/fifo_queue_enqueue' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

This led me to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4094) discussion, where this was solved by "Putting the QueueRunner logic outside the tf.cond() context". However having the Queues IN there is the whole point of my condition, since when I run them (specifically the dequeue-op), they jump to the next sample in line.

**Is there at all a way to make the graph reuse its already loaded data** (or would that be kind of "cyclic" and isn't supported?). I'm out of depth... any ideas?

---

For reference the whole "ResampleLayer" code block:

```
with tf.variable_scope('ResampleLayer'):
    resample_n = args.resample_n   # user-defined  
    resample_i = 0  # resample counter, when 0 it generates new data, then counts up to resample_n

    # dummy placeholders, needed for first run since tf.cond() doesn't do lazy evaluation
    self.batch_img = tf.constant(0., dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch_size]+shape_img)
    self.batch_label = tf.constant(0., dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch_size]+shape_label)
    self.batch_weights = tf.constant(0., dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch_size]+shape_weights)

    def net_data_layer():
        # run the data layer to generate a new batch
        self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights = \
            data_layer.data_TFRqueue(dataset_pth, batch_size=batch_size)
        return self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights

    def resample_data():
        # just forward the existing batch
        return self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights

    with tf.variable_scope('ResampleLogic'):
        t_resample_n = tf.Variable(self.resample_n, tf.int8)
        t_resample_i = tf.Variable(self.resample_i, tf.int8)

        # Determine when to resample. Pure Python equivalent:
        # resample = False if resample_i == 0 else True
        resample = tf.cond(tf.equal(t_resample_i, tf.constant(0)), lambda: tf.constant(False), lambda: tf.constant(True))

        # "Loop" the resample counter. Pure Python equivalent:
        # resample_i = resample_i + 1 if resample_i < resample_n else 0
        tf.cond(t_resample_i < t_resample_n, lambda: t_resample_i + 1, lambda: tf.constant(0))

    # the actual intended branching of the graph
    self.batch_img, self.batch_label, self.batch_weights = \
        tf.cond(resample, 
                lambda: resample_data(), 
                lambda: net_data_layer())

## NETWORK
self.output_mask = self._build_net(self.batch_img, ...)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: At this time, one should avoid using Queues/Runners and use `tf.data` instead.